# What's the difference between Yodlee TransactionView's `transactionType` and `transactionsBaseType`?

Tags: yodlee

What's the difference between Yodlee TransactionView's `transactionType` and `transactionBaseType`?

They seem to serve the exact same purpose, however they hold different values ("unknown" vs "debit" or "credit"). We're using Yodlee SDK version 11.0.

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

transactionBaseType returns general transaction category with one of 4 values:

TRANSACTION_BASE_TYPE_ID    TRANSACTION_BASE_TYPE 
1                           credit
2                           debit
3                           other
4                           unknown

TransactionType returns the more specific transaction type which will be one of 224 possible values. I tried posting it here but table displays aren't supported on SO. If you would like the full listing send a request over on our contact form http://solutions.yodlee.com/web-inquiry.html. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't explain why we get "unknown" in transactionBaseType and "debit" in transactionType. Is there any reason for that or is that a bug?

Answer (score 0):

At Yodlee from data perspective transaction types are mostly used for investment,loan and mortgage type of accounts and not used generally for banking and credit card accounts as for banking and credit card both are same thing. Tranasction Base type typically represents whether the transaction is going to add up money into your account(credit) or is going to remove money from your account(debit). Transaction type basically represent what is the type of a transaction which was done. E.g. in investment you can have a transaction type as "sell" or "buy" or many different things. Now "sell" means debit from your investment account and "buy" means credit to your investment account.